# pgfplot x axis ticks aligned with a matrix beneath |

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

How can I make something like this as shown in the image using pgfplots in latex.[image]

I want the x-axis tick marks aligned with the other texts as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of achcheived it with

```
\begin{axis}[
 xticklabels={
    $0$\\\textcolor{blue}{\boxed{u_0}},
    $1$\\$h_1u_0$\\\textcolor{blue}{\boxed{u_1}},
    $2$\\$h_2u_0$\\$h_1u_1$\\\textcolor{blue}{\boxed{u_2}},
    $3$\\$h_3u_0$\\$h_2u_1$\\$h_1u_2$\\\textcolor{blue}{\boxed{u_3}},
    $4$\\$h_4u_0$\\$h_3u_1$\\$h_2u_2$\\$h_1u_3$\\\textcolor{blue}{\boxed{u_4}},
    $5$\\$h_5u_0$\\$h_4u_1$\\$h_3u_2$\\$h_2u_3$\\$h_1u_4$\\\textcolor{blue}{\boxed{u_5}},
    $6$\\$h_6u_0$\\$h_5u_1$\\$h_4u_2$\\$h_3u_3$\\$h_2u_4$\\$h_1u_5$\\\textcolor{blue}{$\ddots$},
    $7$\\$h_7u_0$\\$h_6u_1$\\$h_5u_2$\\$h_4u_3$\\$h_3u_4$\\$h_2u_5$\\$\vdots$,
    $8$\\$h_8u_0$\\$h_7u_1$\\$h_6u_2$\\$h_5u_3$\\$h_4u_4$\\$h_3u_5$\\$\vdots$,
    $9$\\$h_9u_0$\\$h_8u_1$\\$h_7u_2$\\$h_6u_3$\\$h_5u_4$\\$h_4u_5$\\$\vdots$,    
    ~~~$\cdots~k $\\$\dots$\\$\dots$\\$\dots$\\$\dots$\\$\dots$\\$\dots$\\\textcolor{blue}{$\vdots$},
    },
    xticklabel style   = {align=center},
    axis lines=left,
]

%plots

\end{axis}
```